# How to detect origin/debug a Lexer's null values

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

I've implemented a basic grammar for ANTLR4 to build a JavaScript interpreter
from a Simple Javascript-esque language.

When I run my script to transform the code (parsing/generation/transpilation) I get 
`TypeError: ctx.INT is not a function` which comes from the transpiler file.

#### This is my script to compile

```
var fs = require('fs');
var antlr4 = require('antlr4');
var buildAst = require('./build-ast');
var mylangTranspiler = require('./mylang-transpiler');


function runScript(inputText) {
    var ast = buildAst(inputText);
    var transpiler = new mylangTranspiler();
    antlr4.tree.ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(transpiler, ast);
    // eval(transpiler.output);

    fs.writeFile("./main.js", transpiler.output, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
}

var contents = fs.readFileSync('./tests/test.mylang', 'utf8');
console.log(contents);

runScript(contents);

module.exports = runScript;
```

#### This is the place where the error gets caught

```
mylangTranspiler.prototype.resolveExpr = function(ctx) {
    console.log(ctx);
    if (ctx.INT() != null) {
        return ctx.INT().getText();
    } else if (ctx.ID() != null) {
        return ctx.ID().getText();
    } else if (ctx.STRING() != null) {

        return ctx.STRING().getText().replace(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}/g, '" + $1 + "');
    } else return "undefined";
}
```

#### This is my grammar file

```
grammar mylang;

compilationUnit: stmt*;

stmt
    : assignStmt
    | invocationStmt
    ;

assignStmt: SET ID TO expr;
invocationStmt: ID ((expr COMMA)* expr)?;

expr: expr (MUL | DIV) expr  # MulDiv
    | expr (ADD | SUB) expr  # AddSub
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN     # Parens
    | ID                     # ID
    | INT                    # Int
    | STRING                 # String
    ;

INT: [0-9]+;
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;
ID: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

COMMA: ',';
SAY: 'show';
SET: 'set';
TO: 'to';

MUL: 'times';
DIV: 'by';
ADD: 'add';
SUB: 'sub';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

What i've noticed is that in the Lexer file there are some 'null' value occurencies which i suspect is the reason INT() is null while it shouldnt

#### Lexer file

```
mylangLexer.prototype.channelNames = [ "DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL", "HIDDEN" ];

mylangLexer.prototype.modeNames = [ "DEFAULT_MODE" ];

mylangLexer.prototype.literalNames = [ null, null, null, null, "','", "'show'", 
                                        "'set'", "'to'", "'times'", "'by'", 
                                        "'add'", "'sub'", "'('", "')'" ];

mylangLexer.prototype.symbolicNames = [ null, "INT", "STRING", "ID", "COMMA", 
                                         "SAY", "SET", "TO", "MUL", "DIV", 
                                         "ADD", "SUB", "LPAREN", "RPAREN", 
                                         "WS" ];

mylangLexer.prototype.ruleNames = [ "INT", "STRING", "ID", "COMMA", "SAY", 
                                     "SET", "TO", "MUL", "DIV", "ADD", "SUB", 
                                     "LPAREN", "RPAREN", "WS" ];

mylangLexer.prototype.grammarFileName = "mylang.g4";
```

What im trying to achieve is basic calculator operations, variable assignments and printing to the console but with a different syntax which will get transpiled to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a parser rule with labeled alternatives, each alternative will get its own subclass and only that subclass will have the getter methods corresponding to that alternative's subrules. So given your grammar, you have the following subclasses of `ExprContext`:

- `MulDivContext`
- `AddSubContext`
- `ParensContext`
- `IDContext`
- `IntContext`
- `StringContext`

And of those, only `IntContext` has an `INT()` method. So you should not call `INT()` on an `ExprContext` unless you first make sure that it's actually an `IntContext`.

ANTLR-generated listeners and visitors will have `enter` and `exit` or `visit` methods for each labeled alternative, so the way you'd make sure that you're dealing with an `IntContext` would be that you define `visitIntContext(ctx)`, `visitStringContext(ctx)` etc. instead of `visitExprContext(ctx)` and then you'd know that `ctx` can only ever have the type corresponding to that alternative.

Comment: i kind of get what you're saying but i wasnt able to find a way to debug my listeners, i was trying figure whether i could put something like a debugger when code reaches that place so i can investigate the other members of the ctx so i can build corresponding logic around it.

Comment: @Shiroe Sure, you can set breakpoints in listener methods just like in any other method. You can also `console.log` the context object, which will also show you all its members.

Comment: Yes, i begin to understand now. I was able to add a console log to see the ctx object but i cannot find a way to identify which is the current subclass so i can call INT() or STRING() etc..

Comment: @Shiroe As I said, if you define the proper listener methods such as `enterInt`/`exitInt`, `enterString`/`exitString` etc. instead of `enterExpr`/`exitExpr`, you'll know which type of context you have simply based on which listener method was called. You can also check using `instanceof`.